# Why doesn't Valgrind detect usage of uninitialized variable?

Tags: c++, debugging, valgrind

As I understand Valgrind should report errors when code contains usage of uninitialized variables. In this toy example below `printer` is uninitialized, but program "happily" prints message anyway.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Printer {
    public:
        void print() {
            std::cout<<"I PRINT"<<std::endl;
        }
};


int main() {
    Printer* printer;
    printer->print();
};
```

When I test this program with Valgrind it doesn't report any errors.

Is it expected behavior? And if yes, why so?

Comment: `print()` isn't virtual, so the entire call can be bound at compile time.

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations? You code has UB, it is entirely possible that the optimizer just called `print`.

Comment: Your `Printer::print()` doesn't modify the object, so it doesn't actually *need* a valid `this` pointer. And since dereferencing a uninitialized pointer is UB the compiler can do whatever it wants, so it probably just inlined `print()` straight into `main()` - take a look at the disassembly if you want to know what happened.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I compiled it without optimizations, but it still prints the message

Comment: First of all, this UB would have easily been detected by clang/gcc using `-Wuninitialized` (which is part of `-Wall`). And to detect this kind of UB on runtime, you may check the `-fsanitize=...` options of your compiler.

Comment: Valgrind isn't so much about C++ as it is about runtime correctness. If you want C++ correctness analysis, you might try a tool like ASAN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The variable is actually never used.

1. The method call is inlined<sup>1</sup>, so the variable is not passed as an argument.
2. The method itself doesn't use `this` in any way, so the variable is not used at all.

Above is independent of turning optimizations on or off.

As a matter of fact, in optimized code the variable will never exist at all - not even as memory allocation.

Question about a similar case: [Extern variable only in header unexpectedly working, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098518/extern-variable-only-in-header-unexpectedly-working-why)
.

---

<sup>1</sup> All methods defined in the class body are inlined by default.

#### Is it an Undefined Behavior?

**Yes it is.** Calling the method requires `this` to point at an actual, initialized intance of object to be well-formed. As Nir Friedman points out, compiler is free to assume that and optimize on that base (and IIRC this kind of optimizations can happen even with `-O0`!).

I'd personally expect the specific code in question to work in any practical conditions (as the pointer value is really irrelevant), but I would never rely on that. *You should fix your code right now.*

#### Detection

To detect usage of uninitialized variables in Clang/GCC, use option `-Wuninitialized` (or simply use `-Wall`, which includes this flag).

`-Wuninitialized` should mostly cover use of stack-allocated memory, though I guess some use of stack-allocated arrays may still slip. Some compilers may support including extra runtime checks for uninitialized reads with `-fsanitize=...` options, like [`-fsanitize=memory` in Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html) (thx, [chtz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6870253/chtz)). These checks should cover the edge cases as well as the use of heap-allocated memory.

Comment: Even without optimizations it works and Valgrind doesn't report anything. But if I replace output line by `std::cout<<"I PRINT "<<this<<std::endl;` then it still works but Valgrind reports error. So I suppose you are right that this program just never uses unitialized `this`

Comment: Yes, the variable is never used regardless of optimization. However, unoptimized code may still allocate memory for this pointer. Optimized code won't.

Comment: It is definitely ub, and in particular this has burned a lot of people who depended on this and wrote branches if this == nullptr which were optimized out.

Comment: Good point about `this == nullptr` which is relying on this behavior being consistent. I rephrased the section on UB to clearly say that this is UB and should never be used.

Answer (score 0):

The `main()` function has undefined behaviour, since `printer` is uninitialised and the statement  `printer->print()` both accesses the value of `printer` and dereferences it via `->` and the call of the member function.

Practically, however, a compiler is permitted to handle undefined behaviour by simply assuming it is not present.   Then the compiler can, if it chooses, follow a chain of logic;

- When it sees a statement like `printer->print()` this means it is allowed to reason that `printer` has a value that can be accessed and dereferenced without introducing undefined behaviour.
- Based on this reasoning, it is then permitted to assume that `printer` must have been initialised (by some means invisible to the compiler) to point at a valid object.
- Based on this assumption, it can reason that the statement `printer->print()` will result in a call of `Printer::print()`.
- Since the compiler can see the definition of `Printer::print()`, it can simply inline it, and execute the statement `std::cout<<"I PRINT"<<std::endl`.
- Since it doesn't need to access `printer` at all to produce that output, it can optimise out any reference to the variable named `printer` in `main()`.

If a compiler follows the above sequence of logic, the program will simply print `I PRINT` and exit, without accessing any memory in a way that might trigger a report from Valgrind.

If you think the above sounds far-fetched, then you are mistaken.   LLVM/Clang is one compiler that notionally follows a chain of logic very similar to what I have described.    For more information have a look at the the LLVM Project Blog [link to first article](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), [second article](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html), and 
[third article](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html).